# Counting instances of 0 or 1 to series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

If my dataframe uses a column with instances of values 0 or 1 that I wish to count, what is the syntax for iterating through the column labelling 0 or 1 against an index.

this:

```
output = df.Series([0,1], index= ['no', 'yes'])
```

will return:

```
no    0
yes       1
dtype: int64
```

whereas I want to get an overall no/yes labelled count of 0 or 1 for the entire column.

the actual dataframe is related to the scikit-learn data where I've created a target column on the end of the dataset thus:`worst concave points  worst symmetry  worst fractal dimension  target

 0                 0.26540          0.4601                  0.11890     0.0`

Attempting to map like this:

```
    status = {0:'Malignant', 1:'Benign'}
    cancerdf['target'] = cancerdf['target'].map(status)
```

results in a

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm trying to return a series, but seem to be going off track.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df[column_name].value_counts()` followed by reindexing with no/yes?

Comment: Not sure, possibly not - using the [column_name] results in : local variable 'column_name' referenced before assignment

Comment: Pandas `.describe` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `rename` or `map`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0,1], size=10))
print (s)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    1
8    1
9    0
dtype: int32

d = {0:'No', 1:'yes'}
print (s.value_counts().rename(index=d))
No     7
yes    3
dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
d = {0:'No', 1:'yes'}
print (s.map(d).value_counts())
No     7
yes    3
dtype: int64
```

Or maybe need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice([0,1], size=10)})

d = {0:'No', 1:'yes'}
df['A'] = df['A'].map(d)
print (df)
     A
0   No
1  yes
2   No
3   No
4   No
5   No
6   No
7  yes
8  yes
9   No
```

EDIT:

I think problem is `type` of your data in column `target` are not `int`, but `float`.

So need:

```
status = {0:'Malignant', 1:'Benign'}
cancerdf['target'] = cancerdf['target'].astype(int).map(status)
```

Od if it doesnt work, there are some data which are not numeric and solution is use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replace them to `NaN`, then convert them to some `int` like `2` and last convert to `int`:

```
cancerdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'Target':[1,0,1,'d', 'nan', np.nan]})
print (cancerdf)
  Target
0      1
1      0
2      1
3      d
4    nan
5    NaN

status = {0:'Malignant', 1:'Benign'}
cancerdf['Target'] = pd.to_numeric(cancerdf['Target'], errors='coerce') \
                       .fillna(2).astype(int).map(status)

print (cancerdf)
      Target
0     Benign
1  Malignant
2     Benign
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
```

Comment: Can you edit your question? Because bad formatiing of comments. also add your code. Thank you.

Comment: Don't know if this has a bearing, but the target column is Name: Target, dtype: float64

Comment: Sorry, `NaN`s cause values are  converted to `float`, you can check it by `print (df[df['Target'].isnull()])`

Comment: I've looked at both the above means of mapping, but both get type errors.

Comment: Maybe problem in my side, I have typo `to_numericE`. Please check edited answer with sample. If need, is possible use `.fillna(0)` or `.fillna(1)`

Comment: As far I understand from the data, there aren't any gaps in it. The issue still persists with the type errors. Also - the print (df(df etc - doesn't work.

Comment: `cancerdf['Target'] = pd.to_numeric(cancerdf['Target'], errors='coerce') \
                       .fillna(2).astype(int).map(status)` doest work? What is error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146268/discussion-between-maxrussell-and-jezrael).